# Unable to update ZF2 application - Composer update failed

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

Unable to self-update my zf2 application via cmd getting error like that

```
[Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]

Filesystem exception:

Composer update failed:
The "D:\xampp\htdocs\measureup\composer.phar" file could not be written
```

Command use for it:

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Comment: My money is on fs permissions; ensure you have write permissions for that directory.

Comment: application in local environment please can explain in brief because am newer in zend.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the composer executable file. You do nothing with the zend framework in this command line.

Updating Composer fails because the user account you are using has no write permissions to the file that needs to be written for the update.

If you did not want to update Composer, but to update the dependencies of your application, run `php composer.phar update`. Note that this is not `self-update`.